chaining NOT EXISTS OR EXISTS in SQL
I have these two queries:
KKS_GidNumer IN (
    SELECT
        T1.KKS_GidNumer
    FROM
        CDN.Konta T1
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                CDN.Konta T2
            WHERE
                T1.KKS_GidNumer = T2.KKS_GidNumer
                AND T1.KKS_Konto IN ('konto1', 'konto2', 'konto3')
                AND cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) IN ('ope1', 'ope2', 'ope3')
        )
)

and
    KKS_GidNumer IN (
        SELECT
            T1.KKS_GidNumer
        FROM
            CDN.Konta T1
        WHERE
            EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    1
                FROM
                    CDN.Konta T2
                WHERE
                    T1.KKS_GidNumer = T2.KKS_GidNumer
                    AND (
                        T1.KKS_Konto LIKE '01%'
                        OR T1.KKS_Konto LIKE '02%'
                    )
                    AND cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) IN ('ope4', 'ope5')
            )
)

Both work fine.
I need to combine them into one query.The result should be the result of the first or second query, depending on the value of 'ope'. 'Ope' in the first and second query is always different.
If I put an OR condition between query 1 and 2 ( query1 OR query2), only query1 works. Query2 as if it did not exist.
If I put an AND condition between query 1 and 2 ( query1 AND query2), only query2 works. Query1 as if it did not exist.
Edit
Maybe I explained it wrong. Ope is the program operator (ope1,ope2,ope3,ope4,ope5).
If ope1 or ope2 or ope3 is logged in, query 1 is to be executed. They do not see the lines containing KKS_Konto IN (konto1,konto2,konto3).
If ope4 or ope5 is logged in, query 2 is to be performed. They only see lines containing KKS_konto (LIKE '01%' OR LIKE '02%').
Separately these queries work fine. I need to combine these queries.
Three outcomes are possible:

the first query is true and the second one is false
the first one is false and the second one is true
the first and second are false - then there is no filtering, the logged in operator sees everything.

Sample data:
Of course the real table contains thousands of rows.
Fragment of the table CDN.Konta


Please read How To Make A Good Example, then improve your question as explained.

UPDATED ANSWER (after sample data provided)
As said below you need union of your query, added column as query id (src) and Case expressions.
New is that you will need third query for all rows to be returned since your filtering is very specific. Note that I use operator as a cte since there is no function to fetch it. Changing the operator in ope cte changes the resultset.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table 
  konta  AS 
    ( Select 'konto1' as konto,    1 as kks_gidnumer    Union All
      Select 'konto2',    2    Union All
      Select 'konto3',    3    Union All
      Select 'konto4',    4    Union All
      Select 'konto5',    5    Union All
      Select 'konto6',    6    Union All
      Select 'konto7',    7    Union All  
      Select '01-200',    8    Union All  
      Select '01-300',    9    Union All  
      Select '02-10',    10    Union All  
      Select '02-12',    11   
    );

... declaring ope in a cte - you don't need that as you have a function fetching the operator. You don't need INNER JOIN ope either - just adjust the code to use your function ( cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) )...
WITH    
  ope AS ( Select 'ope9' as operator )

... in the main SQL I moved your ope conditions from your subqueries to the outer Where clause within Case expression. The third unioned query ( 'q3' ) is added to fetch all the data (as in your third desired outcome)
--    S Q L :
SELECT k.konto, k.kks_gidnumer
FROM
  ( Select k.konto, k.kks_gidnumer, 'q1' as src
    From   konta k
    Where  kks_gidnumer IN( SELECT T1.KKS_GidNumer
                            FROM konta T1
                            WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                               FROM konta T2
                                               WHERE T1.KKS_GidNumer = T2.KKS_GidNumer AND 
                                                     T1.konto IN ('konto1', 'konto2', 'konto3') 
                                            )
                         )
UNION ALL
    Select k.konto, k.kks_gidnumer, 'q2' 
    From   konta k
    Where  kks_gidnumer IN( SELECT T1.KKS_GidNumer
                            FROM konta T1
                            WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                           FROM konta T2
                                           WHERE T1.KKS_GidNumer = T2.KKS_GidNumer AND 
                                               ( T1.konto LIKE '01%' OR T1.konto LIKE '02%' ) 
                                        )
                         )
UNION ALL
    Select k.konto, k.kks_gidnumer, 'q3' 
    From   konta k
  ) k
INNER JOIN ope ON(1 = 1)
WHERE      k.src = Case When ope.operator IN('ope1', 'ope2', 'ope3') Then 'q1'
                        When ope.operator IN('ope4', 'ope5') Then 'q2'
                   Else 'q3'
                   End

/*  R e s u l t :    (for ope 1,2,3)
KONTO   KKS_GIDNUMER
------  ------------
konto4             4
konto5             5
konto6             6
konto7             7
01-200             8
01-300             9
02-10             10
02-12             11    */

/*  R e s u l t :    (for ope 4,5)
KONTO   KKS_GIDNUMER
------  ------------
01-200             8
01-300             9
02-10             10
02-12             11    */


The queries should be unioned (Union All) and if you add to both of them a column that would identify the query then you could use Case expression to test your condition and filter the result as you wish.
Something like here:
SELECT test
FROM (  Select 1 as test, 'q1' as src                 -- first query
        Where NOT EXISTS (Select 'A'  Where 1 = 2)
      UNION ALL
        Select 2 as test, 'q2' as src                 -- second query
        Where  EXISTS (Select 'A'  Where 1 = 1)
     )
WHERE  src = Case When 1 = 1 Then 'q1' Else 'q2' End  -- Case controls the result

... this will fetch the first query resultset.
TEST
----
   1

... if you change the condition in outer Where clause to 1 != 1 then you'll get the second query resultset
TEST
----
   2

... and if you remove Where clause the result will be Union All of both queries
TEST
----
   1
   2

Seee the fiddle here.
Answer to your Edit and outcomes:

the first query is true and the second one is false
the first one is false and the second one is true
the first and second are false - then there is no filtering, the logged in operator sees everything.

...
WHERE  src = Case When q1 condition is true And q2 condition is true
                  Then src   -- outcome 3. shows all rows from both unioned queries ( src = src )
                  When q1 condition is true
                  Then 'q1'  -- outcome 1. shows query 1
                  When q2 condition is true
                  Then 'q2'  -- outcome 2. shows query 2
             Else Null -- This is not needed (Null is default here) but if both conditions are false there will be no rows returned   
             End 

Keep in mind  that Case expression is sequential, meaning that first WHEN part satisfied THEN value is returned and Case is exited. That is why your outcome 3 is in the first WHEN of Case expression.

Why do you have all those WHERE clauses that only contain constants? 1 = 1 is always true, 1 = 2 is always false.

Therefore NOT EXISTS (Select 'A'  Where 1 = 2) is always true.

@Barmar Those are just placeholders for Op's Exists / Not Exists code. The answer shows the logic of selecting one or another query depending on some conditions.

Using placeholders like that creates confusion. It would be helpful to provide a specific answer, rather than an abstract one that requires interpretation (and is likely to be mis interpreted).

@AD7six I aggree about confusion, but with no sample data provided and no expected result - there are no specific answers, just the abstract ones showing basic logic that could help...

there are no specific answers + Those are just placeholders for Op's Exists / Not Exists code How does one reconcile these two contradictory statements? Generally if you're going to answer a question - please do actually answer the question (not an abstract interpretation of the question) and don't just hint the OP of what to do. If the best you can do is hint a solution - then the question is unclear and shouldn't be answered at all until clarified :).

@AD7six As I see it - the question could be reduced to: quote "The result should be the result of the first or second query, depending on the value of 'ope" end quote. The ope is used in EXISTS queries. I answered how to get quoated result using dummy sample data and dummy EXTRACT queries. I'd call it abstract, yes, but usefull. All the logic is explained in first sent ence: - union - query id - case expression filter.

It is EXISTS, not extract, offcourse... Sorry

@doctor I understand your concept, but I'm having trouble with the syntax and can't put it together. I can't attach what I wrote, so there's no way to correct it.

@benek Provide some sample data that is reflecting  your context and I'll do it...

@doctor I edited my post and included sample data.

@benek Just posted the UPDATED ANSWER (after sample data provided). Please check it out and let me know if it suits you.

@benek And, btw, d r  are my initials - not the title/degree ....

@benek You can see the fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/Gez_7SEc

select KKS_GidNumer
from CDN.Konta
where cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) like 'ope[1-3]'
          and KKS_Konto like 'konto[1-3]'
   or cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) like 'ope[4-5]')
          and KKS_Konto like '0[12]%' then 1 end
   or cdn.polaczenieinfo(4) not like 'ope[1-5]';

Depending on the indexing if might be beneficial to use the list of literal "in" values rather than the like pattern.
